# how to use OutputCache in a userControl in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, outputcache, dynamic-usercontrols

I have a aspx page that have this piece of code to load a usercontrol loaded from database

```
Control userControl = new Control();

userControl = LoadControl(userControlName);

((HiddenField)userControl.FindControl("HiddenFieldCategoryID")).Value = categoryID.ToString();

((HiddenField)userControl.FindControl("HiddenFieldNewsID")).Value = newsID.ToString();

((HiddenField)userControl.FindControl("HiddenFieldTypeID")).Value = typeID.ToString();

PlaceHolder3.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

and the ascx have an outputcache

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration=10 VaryByParam="none" %>
```

when i browse the page 
this error comes out

> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Content_SectionNews.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Documents
>   and Settings\Administrator\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2005\Projects\AnaweenNews.root\AnaweenNews\anaween
>   website\Content\SectionNews.aspx.cs:127
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   +14 System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +50 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3615;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type that returned from the LoadControl it will be PartialCachingControl, please follow the steps to how use the PartialCachingControl:

```
PartialCachingControl userControl = LoadControl(userControlName) as PartialCachingControl;

PlaceHolder3.Controls.Add(userControl);

if(userControl.CachedControl != null)
{
    ((HiddenField)userControl.CachedControl.FindControl("HiddenFieldCategoryID")).Value = categoryID.ToString();    

    ((HiddenField)userControl.CachedControl.FindControl("HiddenFieldNewsID")).Value = newsID.ToString();

    ((HiddenField)userControl.CachedControl.FindControl("HiddenFieldTypeID")).Value = typeID.ToString();
}
```